# Pass mysqli object to class

Tags: php

I want to pass a mysqli object to a class. I create the object in one file:

```
$host = 'host';
$user = 'username';
$pw = 'pw';
$db = 'db';

$link = new mysqli($host,$user,$pw,$db);
```

which is included in one page:

```
include 'php/mysql.php';
include 'php/classes/Class.Dataconnector.php';
$dc = new Dataconnector($link);
```

and the class looks like this:

```
class Dataconnector {
    protected $_link;
    protected $_stub;

    function __construct(mysqli $link) {
        $_link = $link;
    }

    public function getPageContent($stub) {
        $query = "select * from contents where pageId = (select id from pages where stub = '$stub')";
        $result = mysqli_query($_link,$query);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in \php\classes\Class.Dataconnector.php on line 18
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$this` when accessing the class property `$_link` in your class.

In your constructor, you have:

```
$_link = $link;
```

This should be:

```
$this->_link = $link;
```

In your `getPageContent()` method you have:

```
$result = mysqli_query($_link,$query);
```

This should be:

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->_link,$query);
```

Comment: It's not global, it's an object property.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Sorry, good catch on the terminology (not sure what I was thinking =P). Updated my wording =]